# "You'll should..." - is that correct?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, future-tense

Just found this in a book I read - *"**You'll should** not take this strategy far, as...."*

Why did the author use this construction (will + should)? Is it correct (personally, I don't think so, but I am not a native speaker) and what does it mean?

Thank you very much

Comment: A misprint for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have googled it as an exact match "You'll should" and I have found this in many other places, books included. I think it is a misprint too but just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not grammatical in any variety of English, as far as I know. I suspect that either the writer changed their mind part way through the sentence, or else (because the "'ll" is often so faintly pronounced) they have an erroneous idea that there is supposed to be a "ll" there when writing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a typo or misprint, or it could be the regional grammar construction of [multiple modals](http://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/multiple-modals). The Yale page on this construction says that "multiple modals are common across a wide geographical area and are not stigmatized", but I think this should be understood as referring to attitudes in areas where they are used. For speakers who don't use them, this construction is very likely to sound non-standard or like a mistake. It may be helpful for non-native speakers to be aware that some native speakers use this construction, but I wouldn't recommend using it yourself.